# URI scheme in iOS13 is deprecated?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I was trying to go through documentation but I am not able to see If Apple has mentioned anywhere that URI Scheme is deprecated?

Is there any cons of using URI scheme in iOS 13?

Edit: 
Deeplink with URL Scheme in my application was working totally fine for iOS 12 and it stopped working for me in iOS 13.

Comment: so, why do you think they did it? or why do you think they might have did it?

Comment: @Michael One of the most important reason is Universal links allow unique url which makes it more secured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the new SceneDelegate, I used scene(_:openURLContexts:). Previously handling URL Schemes was done in the AppDelegate.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene